# Getting value from nested dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am looking for a nice and efficient way to get particulars values of a dictionary.

```
{

   "online_apply":{
      "value":"true"
   },
   "interview_format":{
      "value":"In-store"
   },
   "interview_time":{
      "value":"4PM-5PM",
   }
}
```

I am trying to transform the dictionary above to:

```
{
   "online_apply": "true",
   "interview_format": "In-store",
   "interview_time": "4PM-5PM"
}
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
{k: v['value'] for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: Perfect solution, very clean